# Constructor use this and super Java

Tags: java, constructor, this, super

I have a superclass named Human with it's constructor. I have also a subclass named Employee with two constructors. I want inside the subclass' constructor call the other subclass' constructor and the superclass' constructor. Look at the following:

```
public class Human {
protected String name;
protected String surname;

public Human(String n, String s){
    name=n;
    surname=s;
}

}
```

and Employee

```
public class Employee extends Human{

int salary;

public Employee(){
    System.out.println("Creating an Employee");
}

public Employee(int salary){
    this();
    super("Markos", "petrou");
    this.salary=salary;
}
}
```

I think this can't work, but i want your opinion. I there any way to do this?

Comment: "call the other subclass' constructor" What do you mean?

Comment: The call to super must be the first line in the constructor, so you can't call both this() and super()

Comment: To do what exactly..?

Comment: This was a stupid example. I wonder if i can call super and this commands in a constructor...

Comment: Make a helper method called `init`, which you can call in both constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `this` and `super` both. In java first line of the constructor is either this or super. If nothing mention then it will call `super()`

Answer (score 1):

this could be the one way to implement:

```
public class Employee extends Human{

   private int salary;

   public Employee(String name, String surname, int salary){
      super(name, surname);
      this.salary=salary;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Java allows only one call to another constructor inside constructor code. Maybe you want to structure your class like this:

```
public class Employee extends Human {

    int salary;

    private void init() {
        System.out.println("Creating an Employee");
    }

    public Employee(){
        init();
    }

    public Employee(int salary){
        super("Markos", "petrou");
        init();

        this.salary=salary;
    }
}
```

By the way, your code is invalid anyway. `Person` should call super constructor inside its parameterless constructor, but it doesn't. Java allows you to implicitly call superclass' parameterless constructor, but `Human` don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want

```
public Employee(){
    System.out.println("Creating an Employee");
}
```

then you should have a default constructor in class `Human` because this will try to call `super()` and you do not have no argument default constructor in super class.

OR

you can call super explicitly like

```
super(name, surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Employee extends Human{
    int salary;
    public Employee(){
        super("Markos", "petrou");
        System.out.println("Creating an Employee");
    }

    public Employee(int salary){
        super("Markos", "petrou");
        this.salary=salary;
    }
}
```

If you accept the name to be set afterwards using setter methodes , you can add a no-argument constructor to Human.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Your sub-classes must call a super-constructor as their first instruction (or a call to another constructor of the same class which first instruction is a super-constructor call).